# How to select rows that fail exclusion constraint

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with rows in it (source) that I am trying to insert into another table (target). The target has an exclusion constraint in place. However, when I do this, some of the rows fail the exclusion constraint. I would like to be able to select these rows in the source, that fail the exclusion constraint. Is this possible?

```
create table target(
id bigint primary key 
,external_data_source_id bigint not null 
,external_id text not null 
,external_id_domain_id bigint not null 
,internal_id bigint not null 
,valid_period tstzrange not null
,EXCLUDE USING gist (external_data_source_id with = , external_id_domain_id with =, internal_id with =, external_id with =, valid_period WITH &&) 
);

create table source(
id bigint primary key 
,external_data_source_id bigint not null 
,external_id text not null 
,external_id_domain_id bigint not null 
,internal_id bigint not null 
,valid_period tstzrange not null
);

insert into source
select 1,1,'text',1,1,tstzrange('2000-01-01','2001-01-01');

insert into source
select 2,1,'text',1,1,tstzrange('2000-01-01','2001-01-01');

insert into source
select 1,'text',1,1,tstzrange('2002-01-01','2004-01-01');

insert into target
select * from source;
```

gives

```
Error: ERROR: conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "target_external_data_source_id_external_id_domain_id_inter_excl"
  Detail: Key (external_data_source_id, external_id_domain_id, internal_id, external_id, valid_period)=(1, 1, 1, text, ["2000-01-01 00:00:00+01","2001-01-01 00:00:00+01")) conflicts with existing key (external_data_source_id, external_id_domain_id, internal_id, external_id, valid_period)=(1, 1, 1, text, ["2000-01-01 00:00:00+01","2001-01-01 00:00:00+01")).
SQLState:  23P01
ErrorCode: 0
```

I would like to select the rows in source that fail this exclusion constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use condition from the exclusion constraint in an exists query:

```
select s1.*
from source s1
where exists (select * 
              from source s2
              where (s2.external_data_source_id, s2.external_id_domain_id, 
                     s2.internal_id, s2.external_id)  
                     = (s1.external_data_source_id, s1.external_id_domain_id, 
                        s1.internal_id, s1.external_id)
                and s1.valid_period && s2.valid_period
                and s1.id <> s2.id
              );
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/PDOE78609

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work. It seems to match all rows. I believe the exists clause is matching the row with itself. I've updated the question with better examples.

Comment: @ThatDataGuy: ah, sorry. You need to add `and s1.id <> s2.id` to the sub-query

Comment: Yeah that is what I figured, still good style though. Is there to do this if there was no id column? Perhaps I should ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @ThatDataGuy: you could use Postgres' internal "row identifier" [ctid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) for that: `and s1.ctid <> s1.ctid` but that is typically quite slow